# What is the proper way to incorporate a downloadable binary as a Gradle dependency?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

(note: I'm aware of [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/docs) but it seems to only support `.jar` and `.aar` files, not direct binaries or executables)

I'm creating a project template that depends on a number of third-party libraries, most of which are available on Maven Central. But there are also a couple of command-line binaries that exist either in a public Git release other stable URL.

As these binaries will be directly used by the Java module I'm authoring, they are a project dependency, but I'm not sure how to best incorporate them into my Gradle build.

I do not plan on making the project template available via Maven, and I do not want to upload the third-party binaries to a Maven repository. Instead, I want consumers of my template to download the binaries when building or running.

I discovered the [gradle-download-task](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task) plugin and have managed to cobble it into a dependency via the following.

```
// build.gradle

plugins {...}

def downloadXXX() {
   mkdir 'bin'
   download {
      src 'https://github.com/.../tagged_release/xxx.exe'
      dest 'bin'
      onlyIfModified true      
   }
   return files("bin/xxx.exe")
}

...
dependencies {
    testImplementation ...
    implementation ...

    implementation downloadXXX()

}
```

This seems to work. The presence of the binary is checked on compile/build tasks and downloaded if missing or stale, but it *smells wrong*. Although I'm new to Gradle, it seems like I should be creating a download *task* instead of just a function, or doing something else entirely.

I know that by not using Maven I'll be sacrificing a lot of built-in versioning support, but I'm more interested in a) having the project dependencies declared/shown in one place and b) allowing consumers of my template to do as much of a one-click setup as possible.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to define a task and download as a dependency to the `compileJava`

```
task downloadBinaries(type: Download) {
    src 'https://github.com/.../tagged_release/xxx.exe'
    onlyIfModified true
    dest "${sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir}/bin"
}

tasks.compileJava.dependsOn(tasks.downloadBinaries)
```

An optional destination could be the `resources` directory, then binaries will be immediately available in the classpath.